# How to enable kernel configs "CONFIG_POWERCAP" and "CONFIG_INTEL_RAPL" in Ubuntu 16.04 kernel

Tags: drivers, kernel, configuration, intel

I want to make use of Intel® RAPL driver to monitor power in Ubuntu 16.04. The link [here](https://01.org/rapl-power-meter) says that we can verify if `CONFIG_POWERCAP` and `CONFIG_INTEL_RAPL` is enabled or no by checking the presence of `intel-rapl` folder in `/sys/class/powercap/intel-rapl`. And, I did not find `intel-rapl` folder at `/sys/class/powercap/intel-rapl`.

How can I enable the kernel configs `CONFIG_POWERCAP` and `CONFIG_INTEL_RAPL`. What is mean by enabling kernel configs? I am working on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide your Intel processor model number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ubuntu kernels you will find that CONFIG_POWERCAP is set to yes, and CONFIG_INTEL_RAPL is set to module, so what you want is already included.

One way to check is to grep each config from the kernel configuration file:

```
doug@s15:~/temp-k-git/linux$ grep CONFIG_POWERCAP /boot/config-4.4.0-141-generic
CONFIG_POWERCAP=y
doug@s15:~/temp-k-git/linux$ grep CONFIG_INTEL_RAPL /boot/config-4.4.0-141-generic
CONFIG_INTEL_RAPL=m
```

That you do not have the sub-directories in `/sys/class/powercap` suggests that your particular Intel processor doesn't have rapl support. However, that link you gave also doesn't seem to work the way they say (I'm not looking into that).

A very good tool for monitoring lots of things with Intel processors (and I think it works now on some AMD procoessors) is turbostat (linu-tools-common package). Example, monitoring processor package power and temperature:

```
doug@s15:~/temp-k-git/linux$ sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show PkgTmp,PkgWatt --interval 15
PkgTmp  PkgWatt
25      3.70
25      3.69
```

However, one can also access the MSRs (Machine Specific Registers) directly if the msr module is loaded (which turbostat loads, or do `sudo mpdprobe msr`) For example the below script monitors processor package temperature and each core temperature and the CPU frequency:

```
#! /bin/dash
#
# temp_mon5 Smythies 2019.01.20
#       package and all cores.
#
# temp_mon4 Smythies 2018.07.24
#       try 0x19c as the temp MSR.
#       was 0x1b1
#
# temp_mon3 Smythies 2016.10.05
#       a simplified version of temp_mon2,
#       for monitoring temp.
#       Note: it is on purpose that -a is not used.
#       Also CPU0 frequency (1 is good enough, when all
#       are loaded).
#
# temp_mon2 Smythies 2016.09.29
#       Monitor Package temperatures.
#       Use clock modulation to control temps.
#       i.e. simulate the second to last level
#       of defense.
#       Use simple primatives.
#       run as sudo
#       hardcoded for my tcc of 98 degrees.
#
echo ... begin package temperature monitoring ...

#
# In case I forgot (which I often do)

modprobe msr

#
# first let the drastic effect of the sudo command decay
# Done later in temp_mon3.

#
# some stuff

COMMANDP="/usr/sbin/rdmsr --bitfield 22:16 -u 0x1B1"
COMMAND0="/usr/sbin/rdmsr --bitfield 22:16 -u --processor 0 0x19C"
COMMAND1="/usr/sbin/rdmsr --bitfield 22:16 -u --processor 1 0x19C"
COMMAND2="/usr/sbin/rdmsr --bitfield 22:16 -u --processor 2 0x19C"
COMMAND3="/usr/sbin/rdmsr --bitfield 22:16 -u --processor 3 0x19C"
COMMANDF="cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_cur_freq"

#
# then get on with it

while [ 1 ];do
  sleep 15
  CPU0_FREQ=$(eval $COMMANDF)
  TEMP_RAWP=$(eval $COMMANDP)
  TEMP_RAW0=$(eval $COMMAND0)
  TEMP_RAW1=$(eval $COMMAND1)
  TEMP_RAW2=$(eval $COMMAND2)
  TEMP_RAW3=$(eval $COMMAND3)
  TEMP_ACTP=$((98-TEMP_RAWP))
  TEMP_ACT0=$((98-TEMP_RAW0))
  TEMP_ACT1=$((98-TEMP_RAW1))
  TEMP_ACT2=$((98-TEMP_RAW2))
  TEMP_ACT3=$((98-TEMP_RAW3))
  echo "$TEMP_ACTP  $TEMP_ACT0  $TEMP_ACT1  $TEMP_ACT2  $TEMP_ACT3   $CPU0_FREQ"
done
```

Example output:

```
doug@s15:~/temp-k-git/linux$ sudo /home/doug/temp2/temp_mon5
... begin package temperature monitoring ...
29  30  30  28  30   1605277
29  28  30  28  29   1605281
30  30  30  28  30   1605248
29  29  30  29  31   1605112
29  30  30  28  30   1605266
29  29  30  29  30   1605359
31  30  30  27  30   1605199
29  30  30  28  29   1605202
30  29  31  27  29   1605042
29  30  30  27  30   1605312
29  30  30  28  31   1605262
29  29  30  29  30   1605304
```

Comment: "you do not have the sub-directories in `/sys/class/powercap` suggests that your particular Intel processor **doesn't have rapl support**" Is there any way to verify it?

Comment: That is why I asked for your processor model, so i could check.

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8350U CPU @ 1.70GHz

Comment: That processor has RAPL support. Everything in my answer should work for you. I do not know how to make it work as per your link.

Comment: @VamshiPulluri : Oh, I did not realize before, your link is to a program one has to compile and run. I did not try it, I prefer turbostat.

Comment: I have realized that `intel_rapl` kernel module is not loaded. Any idea how to install or load this kernel module

Comment: @VamshiPulluri : ? it loads during boot on my system (not sure why or what causes it to load. Does `sudo modprobe intel_rapl` do it for you?

Comment: `sudo modprobe intel_rapl` gives an error (No devices error). I am using Ubuntu in VM (Oracle VirtualBox). Do you think there will be any problem in VM?

Comment: @VamshiPulluri : I have never tried this stuff on a VM. No, I wouldn't expect it to work on a VM, but don't know authoritatively.

Comment: thanks for the turbostat command, it shows power consumption in watts. i was looking for something like that